# NPM START ERROR - This is related to npm not being able to find a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, nodemon

I have a problem with npm, but specifically when starting my project for a simple server using node.js.

hello network

I have a problem with npm, but specifically when starting my project for a simple server using node.js.
I tried to search in forums, videos and articles but the solutions didn't answer me.

The *ERROR* says that the package.json file is not in the directory, but it is - and the file contains "start" directing to the nodemon app.js command.

[My directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axO3a.png)
[Error npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIMuR.png)

Thank you very much

Comment: "The ERROR says that the package.json file is not in the directory" - The screenshot you provided does not mention *package.json* at all.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. [Please post text, not links to images of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Questions should stand on their own. We can't see your package.json, the error doesn't say `package.json is not in the directory`, etc. Did you look at the log file the error says to look at?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that `cmd.exe;` is not found (and not, as you claim, `package.json`). **Note the extra `;` at the end which shouldn't be there.**

Make sure your system's `COMSPEC` environment variable doesn't have this spurious semicolon at the end (if it has, remove it and restart your computer) and also that you don't have any `.npmrc` that overrides the shell with the bad path.

Comment: Thanks a lot - the problem was the exe; I edited the path (removing the semicolon) and it worked